# How to attach Output or error to Email Script in SSIS Event Handler

Tags: c#, ssis

I placed a Scripting Task containing code to send email `On Error` into the `Event Handler`. Now I need to attached or send the output or the error log with the message.

I have searched and cannot find a solution that is clear.

Note: *MailAuthentication* is a class containing authentication information.

Email Code:

```
[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.
SSISScriptTaskEntryPointAttribute]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.
Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{

public static string EmailBody()
{
StringBuilder userMessage = new StringBuilder();
userMessage.Append("Mail Body Text");
userMessage.Append("Mail Body Text");

userMessage.Append("\n\nMail Body Text");
userMessage.Append("\nMail Body Text");
userMessage.Append("\nMail Body Text");

return userMessage.ToString();
}

public void Main()
{
var fromAddress = new MailAddress(MailAuthentication.mailFrom, "From Me");
var toAddress = new MailAddress(MailAuthentication.mailTo, "To Someone");
const string fromPassword = MailAuthentication.password;
const string subject = "Who Shot the couch";

string body = EmailBody().ToString();

var smtp = new SmtpClient
{
Host = MailAuthentication.liveSMTP,
Port = 587,
EnableSsl = true,
DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, fromPassword),
Timeout = 20000
};
using (var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
Subject = subject,
Body = body
})
{
smtp.Send(message);
}
}

enum ScriptResults
{
Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
};

}
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to configure the package log file to write the error log ([example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a8eae1a-f708-485e-ab51-fd35cb1c0438/getting-error-in-ssis-creating-error-log-file)). Then create a package on top off this one that, on error, sends the files using the email task, or your script.

[Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a4f5c388-7435-4f23-8c18-d74040b6b629/getting-validation-errors-from-send-mail-with-attachment)  is a possible solution.